# sending image to dropbox folder in android

Tags: android, image, dropbox

i need to send image to my folder which is in dropbox. i already sent a .txt file with following statement

```
int putFileResult = api.putFile("dropbox", "/Foldername", file);
```

Now i have to send image from SD card, how can send image to dropbox,  how to do this.

i have found some solution to send thumbnails in this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/docs)

but it didnt solved my problem. please tell me the way to send images

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(mFile);
String path = mPath + mFile.getName();
mRequest = mApi.putFileOverwriteRequest(path, fis, mFile.length(), new ProgressListener() {

    @Override
    public long progressInterval() {
        return 500;
    }

    public void onProgress(long bytes, long total) {
        publishProgress(bytes);
    }
});

if (mRequest != null) {
    mRequest.upload();
    return true;
}
```